# javaScript runtime error: Expected ':' on the url provided

Tags: javascript, .net, signalr

i have a project which is written in MVC3,its a signalR,i got the code to edit some part but i see its gives an error,on the following part which says cant start a null refrence:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(FUNCTION....)
```

meaninf the valu of hub is null,the fowlooing are the scripts which are loading:

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/leitwind/dateExtension.min.js?ver=1")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/leitwind/knockoutAutoRefresh.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.2/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")"></script>
```

when i go to the developer option of the browser its showing the error on the last refrence,signalr/hubs which does not exist!im wondering why the project is running on the server but not on the local pc even thought i have the same scripts and anything has been changed,after one day of investigation i thought maybe i should give the address of the server instead of signalr/hubs,with this work around i that error is not threwing any more but i have the following issue,all in all i dont have any idea where i should look

is there something wrong with the url format?
i need to set the address manually in my code in order to get data from the server,for the follwoing part:

```
 $.connection.hub.url ='https://myserver.com/file/signalr/'; 
 $.connection.hub.start().done()
```

Comment: More code/context would be nice so we can help.

Comment: @Stphane when i run the signalr on the localhost does not work,i think its because the hub is on the server,so i need to manually prove the server address for it

Comment: Your question has too few details, please edit your question. It might be a good thing to add the full error stack trace and any code that may be appropriate for us to help. You will find [tips here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Btw, the url seems valid but you may be facing a *CORS* error due to the fact that you are serving content over _HTTPS_ which might not be the case for the page which executes your client code, [see here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#how-to-establish-a-cross-domain-connection).

Comment: @Stphane please take a look on my edited question